# clang 3.1 built binary on Ubuntu 12.04 cannot debug with gdb

Tags: gdb, llvm, clang

ubuntu 12.04.1 
tried with original source clang+llvm 3.0, it works great. After add -g option for clang++, I can use gdb to debug the file with symbols+source.

But if I build clang+llvm 3.1 and use prebuilt binary from 
http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/clang+llvm-3.1-x86_64-linux-ubuntu_12.04.tar.gz

clang++ -g to compile the same sample source code and then use gdb to debug, 
I cannot list sources, and cannot step sources, "next" command will finish executing main function.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug which is still not resolved in trunk.

http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13211

As a workaround you can try to set the break point in the form of source file name and line number instead of function name.

$(gdb) break main.cpp:5